# Will random() ever change?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, random

I have been looking into a development issue that requires the use of pseudorandom number generation to allow the same set of random numbers to be generated for a given seed.
I have currently been looking at using `long random(void)` and `void srandom(unsigned seed)` for this ([man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/random.3.html)), and currently these are generating the same set of random numbers in a Mac app, an iOS app and an iOS app (64-bit) which is what I was hoping. The iOS tests were only in the simulator so I don't know whether this will affect the result.

My main concerns is that this algorithm could change at some point, making the applications we're developing effectively useless with old data. **What are the chances of these algorithms changing / being different on a future device?**

Comment: Anyone discussing RNGs always brings this classic Dilbert strip to mind... http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/ // on-topic: I think @Bathsheba is spot on :)

Comment: They probably will not change, since there are likely many dependencies on them.  But there are no guarantees.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say it's *extremely* likely they will change as the sequence is not guaranteed by any standard.

Why not use your own random number sequence? Even a simple linear congruential generator satisfies most statistical properties of randomness. Here is the formula for such a generator:

```
next_number = (a * current_number + b) % c
```

with

```
a = 1103515245
b = 12345
c = 4294967296
```

These values of a, b, c give you good statistical properties and are quite well known for building *quick and dirty generators*.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the slightest idea about the answer to the question you ask.

If a related question is "How can I be absolutely sure to have the same pseudo-random sequences generated in 10 years time ?", the answer to this question is : don't rely on an external library, write the code explicitly.

Bathsheba proposed [this generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). You can google for "pseudo random generator algorithm". Here is a list of algorithms listed on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators).

Comment: +1 for the link which contains other values for a, b and c (my notation)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, `srandom` did change since Mac OS X 10.7, according to [this blog post](http://kqueue.org/blog/2012/06/25/more-randomness-or-less/). However, this was due
to the way `srandom` was implemented: it tried to access an uninitialized local variable, which
is undefined behavior in C. According to the post, the new compiler used since Mac
OS X 10.7 optimized out the uninitialized memory access, changing its behavior in subtle
ways.

Comment: It's not the random number generator function `srandom` that changed, but the seeding function `srandomdev`. Since the OP uses a fixed seed `srandom` might still produce identical pseudo random values. This, of course, does not change the fact that `srandom` *might* change at any time.